# Assessing the meaning of a metric in a binary design

Tags: hypothesis-testing, binomial-distribution, experiment-design

I try to assess the meaning of  a software metric *lines of code* on bug density with the help of statistical methods. I have information on bugs and other needed software measures for several years. This is my current approach, which I hope can be cross-validated here:

*H_0 (null-hypotheses)*: Bugs are uniformly distributed (in respect of lines of code)

*H_1*: Bugs are not uniformly distributed (in respect of lines of code)

For a time-window *x*, I have the number of bugs and information on all source files. I now split the source files into two groups: small files and large files - each group has the same amount of lines (50% of total lines). This makes it a binary experiment and the probability, under the assumption that bugs are uniformly distributed, is 0.5 if a bug falls into the small or large file group.

[image]

This experiment is now comparable with a coin toss: I have the number of total bugs n, the number of bugs found in the group t, the expected number of bugs (mean: 0.5n), and the standard deviation (sqrt(p(1-p)/n)). I can then calculate the number of standard deviations the number of actual bugs deviates and read its probability from the table.

However, what I'm not sure of, is whether it does make a difference if I split the data into different time-windows. In other words, does it make a difference to the result, if I make this experiment one time (with data over several years) with 50000 bugs or if I split it into lets say 5 experiments with 10000 bugs each?

Thanks for any suggestions and advice!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Cross Validated! At first glance, I would say that experiment does not answer your question. For instance, lets assume that both groups contain half of the bugs observed. However, if a single large file on the second group contains all the bugs for that group, would you say that the bugs are uniformly distributed? The proposed test would not reject $H_0$, but it is clearly false. I would take a step back however: what is your end goal? Is that hypothesis test really translating your objective? How does time plays a role in your analysis? Maybe you could elaborate further.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input! "The proposed test would not reject H0, but it is clearly false."- I think this depends on the view of uniformly distributed bugs. In respect of uniformly distributed bugs over files - yes, in your example the bugs are not distributed uniformly over all files. However, if one looks only at the sum of lines of code, it is uniformly distributed (50% of bugs are in 50% of the lines of code, respectively). I added an image to my question in order to make it more clear.

Comment: Regarding time:  Does it have an impact on the meaning of an experiment if I split it into multiple experiments? E.g., I throw a coin 10.000 times and get 9000 times head -> this is very unlikely and I expect a very signifcant result. But what if would have instead thrown the coin 100 times a 100 times, each time getting 90 times head (in sum also have 10.000 throws and 9000 times head) -> I would have gotten multiple less signficants results. Can I combine the multiple less significant results so I can get an equally signficant result, like of the original experiment?

Comment: I can not agree with the first point you made. If you repeated the test on the large files, i.e. you splited the large files again, one group would have all the bugs, and other none, so you would reject $H_0$ very strongly here. If you have $10$ "large" source code files, each with $50$ lines, the probability of a single one containing all the bugs $5$ is low.

Comment: Could you explain what do you mean by "Bugs are uniformly distributed in the lines of code"? Do you mean that, given any line, it contains a bug with probability $p$ independently of other lines?

Comment: I agree with your first point. However, if you focus only on large files and leave the small files out, it could potentially lead to a bias in the analysis. *"Do you mean that, given any line, it contains a bug with probability p independently of other lines?*"- Yes

Comment: Spliting in large vs small is also biased. Moreover, even if we found a non biased way to split into two groups, I believe the statistical  would still not be the most suitable. In my opinion, with the current formulation, what we can indeed test is if the probability of a line having a bug does not depend of the source file. In that case, I believe a Chi-squared test might be more suitable. I can write an answer explaining if this seems what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, the procedure proposed can be problematic to test the hypothesis. Moreover, given the limited information, i.e. number of bugs per file and file size, I do not know if we can really test the desired hypothesis. What we can instead is to test is if the bugs depends on the source files, and this is somehow related to the initial hypothesis.

Lets rewrite the null as $H_0$: *the probability of finding a bug in a line does not depend on the source file*. If we do not reject this last hypothesis, then we clearly can not have the bugs uniformly distributed in the lines (because they depend on the source files).

Assume we have $\{1,\ldots, F\}$ files, each one consisting of $(b_i, n_i)$, where $b_i$ is the number of bugs in the $i$-th file and $n_i$ is the number of lines. Assuming that lines the lines are independent of each other and it contains a bug with probability $p_i$ for the $i$-th source file, we have $b_i \sim Binom(n_i, p_i)$. In this scenario, the hypothesis $H_0$ translates to

$H_0: p_i = p,\quad i\,\in\,\{1,\ldots,F\}$.

That is, the probability of observing a bug does not depend on the file. Letting $N = \sum_{i=1}^F n_i$ be the total number of lines and $B = \sum_{i=1}^F b_i$ the total number of bugs, we estimate the probability of having a bug in a line as $\hat{p} = \frac{B}{N}$.

To test the null, we can use a [Chi-squared test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson%27s_chi-squared_test#Testing_for_statistical_independence) for homogeneity. This basically compares the expected number of bugs $i$-th line $E_i = n_i\frac{B}{N}$ under the null-hypothesis vs what you actually observed $b_i$ for all files. You calculate the test statistic, compute the p-value using the distribution of $\chi^2$ with $F-1$ degrees of freedom and compare to your significance level.

Rejecting the test implies rejecting that bugs are uniformly distributed in lines. Not rejecting does not imply the bugs are uniformly distributed in lines. They could depend on other variables, for instance, the type of assertions the line contains (function call, assignment, declaration, macro, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your inputs (especially the write up)! I really appreciate it!